# Minimise the result of an expression

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization

What is the minimum value the expression ${a} + 3{b} + 3{c} + {d}$ can have if $$a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{N}$$ 
$${a} \neq {b} \neq {c} \neq {d}$$ 
and the sum of any two variables is not equal to another, ie
$$ {a} + {b} \neq {c}, {b} + {c} \neq {d}, ... $$

The best I can do is show that the minimum occurs when 
$$ b \leq c < a \leq d $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should minimise the expression $a+3b+3c+d$ w.r.t. $b$ and $c$, minimising $a$ and $d$ should come later.

So $b=1$, $c=2$, $a=4$, $d=7$ are the lowest possible numbers satysfying stated requirements, and the sum is equal to $4+3+6+7 = 20$.

Comment: how did you come to a = 4, and d = 7?

Comment: After taking $b=1$ and $c=2$, the lowest possible value $a$ can take is $4$, same reason for $d=7$.

Comment: trial and error then?

Comment: Well, the expression is simple enough to work this way.

Comment: if the expression had more variables, how would you go about it then?